# Como concatenar uma varchar dentro de uma função MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tenho essa função hipotética:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE dado VARCHAR(150);
SET dado = 'teste';
END;
```

Como faço para concatenar a variável `dado`, como por exemplo:

```
SET dado += ' teste2';
```

Testei isso mas não funciona no MySQL.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar a função [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
SELECT CONCAT(primeiro_nome, " ", ultimo_nome) AS Nome_Completo FROM CLIENTE
```

Há como [configurar](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) o MySql para concatenar strings com o operador `||`. Porém sempre utilizei o `CONCAT` pois sempre atendeu as minhas necessidades.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 2):

```
concat(dado,'teste')
```

seria isso?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o concat tanto em um SELECT como dentro de uma FUNCTION.

Usando no SELECT:

```
SELECT CONCAT(coluna_1, " STRING ", coluna_2) AS STRING_CONCATENADA FROM SUA_TABELA
```

[Código no GitHub para referência futura](https://github.com/pcgoncalves/SOpt/blob/master/MySQL/Select/ConcatenarVarchar.sql)

Usando na FUNCTION:

```
CONCAT (string1, string2,…)
```

No seu caso, pelo o que eu entendi, você quer para uma FUNCTION, então ficaria assim:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE dado  varchar(150);
DECLARE concDado varchar(150);
SET dado = 'teste';
SET concDado = CONCAT(dado , ' teste2');
```

[Código no GitHub para referência futura.](https://github.com/pcgoncalves/SOpt/blob/master/MySQL/Function/ConcatenarVarchar.sql)

Abraços